# getting nil when i try to make decode

Tags: json, swift

when i try to make decoder.decode  i get result nil (i check the data and there is data,
data != nil) but the decode not working
I think most likely it is related to the structs, I would love to refine what I am doing wrong.
i added the code below  Thanks for the help

struct codable :

```
struct CoinsList: Codable {
    
    let data:[Coin]?
       
}

struct Coin:Codable {
    
   
    let id:Int?
    let name:String?
    let symbol:String?
    let max_supply:Int64?
    let circulating_supply:Int64?
    let total_supply: Int64?
    let cmc_rank:Int?
    let quote:QuoteData?
       
}

struct QuoteData:Codable {
    
    let USD:CoinPrice?
    
}

struct CoinPrice:Codable {
    
    let price:Double?
    let volume_24h:Double?
    let market_cap:Double?
    
}
```

json:

```
{
  status: {
     timestamp: "2022-10-04T12:34:53.878Z",
     error_code: 0,
     error_message: null,
     elapsed: 20,
     credit_count: 1,
     notice: null,
     total_count: 9462
  },
 data: [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: "Bitcoin",
    symbol: "BTC",
    slug: "bitcoin",
    num_market_pairs: 9760,
    date_added: "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
tags: [
    "mineable",
     "pow",
     "sha-256",
     "store-of-value",
     "state-channel",
     "coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
     "three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
     "polychain-capital-portfolio",
     "binance-labs-portfolio",
     "blockchain-capital-portfolio",
     "boostvc-portfolio",
     "cms-holdings-portfolio",
     "dcg-portfolio",
     "dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
     "electric-capital-portfolio",
     "fabric-ventures-portfolio",
     "framework-ventures-portfolio",
     "galaxy-digital-portfolio",
     "huobi-capital-portfolio",
     "alameda-research-portfolio",
     "a16z-portfolio",
     "1confirmation-portfolio",
     "winklevoss-capital-portfolio",
     "usv-portfolio",
     "placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
     "pantera-capital-portfolio",
     "multicoin-capital-portfolio",
      "paradigm-portfolio"
],
    max_supply: 21000000,
    circulating_supply: 19168887,
    total_supply: 19168887,
    platform: null,
    cmc_rank: 1,
    self_reported_circulating_supply: null,
    self_reported_market_cap: null,
    tvl_ratio: null,
    last_updated: "2022-10-04T12:32:00.000Z",
quote: {
  USD:  {
    price: 19944.28244328565,
    volume_24h: 33376911598.804485,
    volume_change_24h: 35.5843,
    percent_change_1h: 0.10558095,
    percent_change_24h: 3.77987746,
    percent_change_7d: -1.62664338,
    percent_change_30d: 0.4638364,
    percent_change_60d: -14.4615399,
    percent_change_90d: -0.70303523,
    market_cap: 382309696451.4265,
    market_cap_dominance: 39.9685,
    fully_diluted_market_cap: 418829931309,
tvl: null,
last_updated: "2022-10-04T12:32:00.000Z"
}
}
},
```

}

reuqset api :

```
class CoinRestApi {
    
    private let urlCoinList = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest"
    private var coinDataSource:((CoinsList?)->Void)?
    private var coins: CoinsList?
    func getCoinsLists(coinDetaClousre: @escaping (_ coinDataSource:CoinsList?)->Void) {
        
        self.coinDataSource = coinDetaClousre
        
        let url = URL(string: self.urlCoinList)
        
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: ParseCoin)
        dataTask.resume()
        
        
    }
    
    private func ParseCoin(data:Data? , urlResponse:URLResponse? , error:Error?) {
        
        
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            // parse JSON
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                self.coins = try decoder.decode(CoinsList.self, from: data!)
                
            }
            catch  {
                
                print("Parseing Failed")
            }
        }
        if let coinDataSource {
            coinDataSource(coins)
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: `print("Parseing Failed")`-> `print("Parseing Failed: \(error)")`

Comment: And don't make the value optional (using `?`) if they should be present in JSON.

Comment: When you make everything optional in your struct's the decoder will not pick up on any spelling errors or similar in your structs because it will think it's ok that a property isn't there. So my advice is to make all properties non-optional with the exception of course being those that can be null in your json. Once you have done that you should get an error telling you what is wrong. But this requires that you handle the error so change from printing a hardcoded string in the `catch` to printing the actual error, `print(error)`

Comment: Note, what you show is not json data, and you need to have an api key to call the server.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and it worked just fine. The JSON data you shared has a wrong format and as @workingdog said you get **API key missing** when trying to call the URL. So I created a data.json file with the structure fixed and tested the decode method locally and it worked ok. I suggest you use the code below to check the error you are getting, but the problem is not in the Codable structs.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
   self.coins = try decoder.decode(CoinsList.self, from: data!)
}
catch(let error){
    print("Parsing Failed \(error)")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get is probably due to your data model structs not matching the json data from the server.
Try this example code. Since I do not have an api key, I've used the "test" key with
the "sandbox" api, which should be the same as the "pro-api".

```
class CoinRestApi: ObservableObject {
    @Published var coinsList: [Coin] = []
    
    func fetchData(token: String) {
        // var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest")
        
        // for testing, sandbox-api
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://sandbox-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest")
        guard let url = urlComponents?.url else {
            print("Invalid url")
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(CryptoResponse.self, from: data)
                    self.coinsList = results.data
                } catch {
                    print(error) // <-- here important
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = CoinRestApi()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(model.coinsList) { coin in
                VStack {
                    Text(coin.symbol)
                    Text("\(coin.quote["USD"]?.price ?? 0.0)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.fetchData(token: "b54bcf4d-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - CryptoResponse
struct CryptoResponse: Codable {
    let status: Status
    let data: [Coin]
}

// MARK: - Coin
struct Coin: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, symbol, slug: String
    let cmcRank, numMarketPairs, circulatingSupply, totalSupply: Int
    let maxSupply: Int
    let lastUpdated, dateAdded: String
    let tags: [String]
    let platform, selfReportedCirculatingSupply, selfReportedMarketCap: String?
    let quote: [String: Quote]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, symbol, slug
        case cmcRank = "cmc_rank"
        case numMarketPairs = "num_market_pairs"
        case circulatingSupply = "circulating_supply"
        case totalSupply = "total_supply"
        case maxSupply = "max_supply"
        case lastUpdated = "last_updated"
        case dateAdded = "date_added"
        case tags, platform
        case selfReportedCirculatingSupply = "self_reported_circulating_supply"
        case selfReportedMarketCap = "self_reported_market_cap"
        case quote
    }
}

// MARK: - Quote
struct Quote: Codable {
    let price: Double
    let volume24H: Int
    let volumeChange24H, percentChange1H, percentChange24H, percentChange7D: Double?
    let marketCap: Double
    let marketCapDominance: Int
    let fullyDilutedMarketCap: Double
    let lastUpdated: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case price
        case volume24H = "volume_24h"
        case volumeChange24H = "volume_change_24h"
        case percentChange1H = "percent_change_1h"
        case percentChange24H = "percent_change_24h"
        case percentChange7D = "percent_change_7d"
        case marketCap = "market_cap"
        case marketCapDominance = "market_cap_dominance"
        case fullyDilutedMarketCap = "fully_diluted_market_cap"
        case lastUpdated = "last_updated"
    }
}

// MARK: - Status
struct Status: Codable {
    let timestamp: String
    let errorCode: Int
    let errorMessage: String?
    let elapsed, creditCount: Int
    let notice: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timestamp
        case errorCode = "error_code"
        case errorMessage = "error_message"
        case elapsed
        case creditCount = "credit_count"
        case notice
    }
}
```